# Error compiling xamarin forms android app in visual studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have created a Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) and while compiling the android app I am getting this error:

> The "ResolveSdks" task failed unexpectedly

But iOS app is getting compiled successfully.

Comment: can you add your screenshot please ?

Comment: i am new to the forum and not able to add screenshot

Comment: Enable MSBuild diagnostic level logging and add the full formatted error  to your question.